# Can't find code block ide in dash

Tags: software-installation

I have a peculiar problem on my ubuntu 14.04 system. I have installed code block using :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

and it got installed with out any problems. But after that I can't find it from the dash menu. I can't find the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codeblocks` like other programs need a restart to be findable via dash. When you installed codeblocks, please restart, and find it via dash(`codeblocks`).